# PHP Form $_POST foreach stops after first iteration

Tags: php, phpdesktop

I have the below PHP code which picks up the posted form data from another file, executes SELECT queries to find all related data form the various tables (SalesDB, CustDB and ProdDB), and then executes an INSERT INTO query to add a row into the 'SalesDB' table. The form has dynamically added rows, which gives each newly added row a unique ID, for example:

```
...<input type="text" id="prodName_1" name="prodName[]" value="">
...<input type="text" id="prodName_2" name="prodName[]" value="">
.  
.  
...<input type="text" id="prodName_Z" name="prodName[]" value="">
```

However, when the PHP script runs for e.g. 3 rows of product lines, it only executes the $queryinsert query for the first iteration and inserts the first product line of the form. Why won't it loop through the array? See the php script below:

```
<?php

$db = new SQLite3('../xxx.db');
if(!$db){
  echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
  exit;
}

if (empty($_POST['custID'])) {
  $errorMSG = array("No customer selected");
  echo json_encode($errorMSG, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
  exit;
} else {

  $custID = $_POST['custID'];

  $queryInsert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO 'SalesDB'
  (SalesID,CustID,ProdID,ProdQty,ProdPrice,ProdCurr,ProdVAT,SalesPrice,SalesVAT,SalesSum)
  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
  $queryInsert->bindParam(1,$salesID);
  $queryInsert->bindParam(2,$custID);
  $queryInsert->bindParam(3,$prodID);
  $queryInsert->bindParam(4,$prodQty);
  $queryInsert->bindParam(5,$prodPrice);
  $queryInsert->bindParam(6,$prodCurr);
  $queryInsert->bindParam(7,$prodVAT);
  $queryInsert->bindParam(8,$salesPrice);
  $queryInsert->bindParam(9,$salesVAT);
  $queryInsert->bindParam(10,$salesSum);

  $querySalesID = "SELECT MAX(SalesID) AS max_SalesID FROM 'SalesDB'";
  $resultSalesID = $db->query($querySalesID);

  while ($row = $resultSalesID->fetchArray()) {
    $salesID = $row['max_SalesID'] + 1;
  }

  foreach($_POST['prodName'] as $prodName => $value) {
    if (!$value) {
      $errorMSG = array("Empty product fields");
      echo json_encode($errorMSG, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
      exit;
    } elseif ($value == "Product not found") {
      $errorMSG = array("Invalid products in order form");
      echo json_encode($errorMSG, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
      exit;
    }

    $queryProd = "SELECT * FROM `ProdDB` WHERE ProdName LIKE '%$value%'";
    $resultProd = $db->query($queryProd);

    while ($row = $resultProd->fetchArray()) {
      $prodID = $row['ProdID'];
      $prodPrice = $row['ProdPrice'];
      $prodQty = $row['ProdQty'];
      $prodVAT = $row['ProdVAT'];
      $prodCurr = $row['ProdCurr'];
      $salesPrice = $prodQty * $prodPrice;
      $salesVAT = number_format($prodQty * $prodPrice * $prodVAT,2);
      $salesSum = $salesPrice + $salesVAT;
    }
    $result = $queryInsert->execute();
  }
}
?>
```

Please also note that I am aware that I am (most likely) making a lot of mistakes when it comes to security practices or programming standards, but this whole thing (PHPDesktop > https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop) will get packed into an EXE file which will run locally only (no need for an online connection as the SQLite3 DB gets packed in with the EXE), and I am still figuring out how to program this in the first place, so efficient and tidy coding are not high on my list yet ;-)

Comment: @04FS The exit comment only gets triggered in case the $_POST is empty or has the value 'Product not found'. If neither is applicable, it will skip this code and continue to the $queryProd statement, which does not have an exit statement.

Comment: _“Why won't it loop through the array?”_ - have you actually _verified_ it is not doing that? You have _no_ error control whatsoever on your queries - so who’s to say `$queryInsert->execute()` did not just fail silently?

Comment: @04FS If I have 3 rows of data to be inserted, after executing the script I can only see the first line added to the DB, whilst the second and third lines are not in the DB.

Comment: That is _exactly_ what I was referring to - you are looking at the result only, instead of checking what _actually_ happens inside your script! Go and properly debug this. Start by checking if your database queries actually succeeded - _inside your script_.

Comment: @RoyMonden hi, if my answer helped you, please flag it as the accepted one (with the green V)

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues in the script:

**1)** Instead of doing `exit` inside the `foreach`, do `continue` to skip the single actual iteration.

As in the [official documentation](https://www.php.net/continue):

> continue is used within looping structures to skip the rest of the
>   current loop iteration and continue execution at the condition
>   evaluation and then the beginning of the next iteration.

Try this code:

```
  foreach($_POST['prodName'] as $prodName => $value) {
    if (!$value) {
      $errorMSG = array("Empty product fields");
      echo json_encode($errorMSG, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
      continue;
    } elseif ($value == "Product not found") {
      $errorMSG = array("Invalid products in order form");
      echo json_encode($errorMSG, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
      continue;
    }

    $queryProd = "SELECT * FROM `ProdDB` WHERE ProdName LIKE '%$value%'";
    $resultProd = $db->query($queryProd);

    while ($row = $resultProd->fetchArray()) {
      $prodID = $row['ProdID'];
      $prodPrice = $row['ProdPrice'];
      $prodQty = $row['ProdQty'];
      $prodVAT = $row['ProdVAT'];
      $prodCurr = $row['ProdCurr'];
      $salesPrice = $prodQty * $prodPrice;
      $salesVAT = number_format($prodQty * $prodPrice * $prodVAT,2);
      $salesSum = $salesPrice + $salesVAT;
    }
    $result = $queryInsert->execute();
  }
```

**2)** your query are using user inputs without check their contents, so your script maybe open to [SQLInjection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)!

```
$queryProd = "SELECT * FROM `ProdDB` WHERE ProdName LIKE '%$value%'";
```

**3)** if the query does return nothing, the script does not enter in the `while` loop, so it seems that the `foreach` do only one iteration but instead it do all iterations without enter in the `while` because of empty result from that query.

I suggest to you to debug all pieces of your code by printing out variables content using [`var_dump`](https://php.net/var_dump), e.g.:

```
$a = array(1, 2, array("a", "b", "c"));
var_dump($a);
```

Comment: I gave it a try, but it does not make a difference. Also, I would not expect the 'exit' statement to be the issue, because that only gets triggered in case the $_POST is empty or has the value 'Product not found'. If neither is applicable, it will skip this code and continue to the $queryProd statement.

Comment: I have, but sadly I am a novice when it comes to JS and PHP, and as such I have not been able to get the var_dump to work. The problem is that I am working in a system called PHPDesktop (https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop, thats why I am not worries about the SQL injection as this will be packaged into an offline EXE) and therefor do not have a local server running. Further, I do not have a IDE running, but just a code editor (Atom io), hence I have to try getting it to work with trial and error.

Comment: @RoyMonden explain that in your question my editing it. You'll increase the question quality and wou'll may have a solution from whom familiar with your tools